# What are the current theoretical limits on the size of a wormhole?

Tags: gravity, wormholes

What are the current theoretical limits on the size of a wormhole?

Some physicists believe that wormholes could be as small as the Planck length, which is about 10^-35 meters. Others believe that wormholes could be much larger, perhaps even as large as a galaxy.

If they were too large they would collapse under their own gravity.

Comment: *If they were too large they would collapse under their own gravity.* Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Because of too large size their negative mass will decrease and let them to collapse.

Comment: So you don’t have a reference?

Comment: So why other's beleive wormhole could be size of galaxies.

Comment: The whole purpose of using negative energy densities in wormhole metrics is to prevent the wormhole from (1) pinching off before anything—even light— can traverse it and (2) so there are no event horizons (i.e., nothing resembling a black hole appears).